# Why am I getting a matrix of zeros and infs when dividing matrices of the same dimension by element?

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

I'm trying to get two matrices to divide, properly, element by element.

Essentially, `firstd` is a 6x499 and `secd` is 6x498. I first eliminate firstd's extra elements by doing `firstd(:,499)=[];` making it 6x498. Now the next step is to transform firstd into the nominator, `nom=((firstd.^2)+1).^1.5;` My denominator is just `denom=secd;`

Both nom and denom have come out as 6x498 matrices with real, non-zero data for each element. However, when doing `Rlayer=nom./denom`, Rlayer comes out as this ludicrous 6x498 zero-ridden matrix.

I also trimmed out the elements in denom that were =0 by changing them to 0.0001.

Segment of result for Rlayer (Columns 493 through 498)

```
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
-0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
```

Below are two segments of denom (Columns 487 through 492)

```
0.0250    0.0281   -0.0281    0.0125   -0.0500    0.0969
-0.0125    0.0750   -0.1219    0.1094   -0.0938    0.0937
0.0344    0.0406   -0.1094    0.1187   -0.1344    0.1531
0.0001    0.0250    0.0001   -0.0437    0.0500    0.0062
0.0781   -0.0219    0.0094   -0.0125   -0.0188    0.1062
0.0250    0.0438   -0.0812    0.0937   -0.1063    0.1562
```

(Columns 493 through 498)

```
-0.1187    0.1156   -0.0844    0.0688   -0.0406    0.0125
-0.0969    0.1094   -0.0906    0.0469    0.0062   -0.0156
-0.1375    0.1719   -0.1656    0.0781    0.0187   -0.0531
-0.0562    0.1188   -0.1500    0.1438   -0.1187    0.1187
-0.1781    0.2281   -0.2156    0.1750   -0.1250    0.0812
-0.1750    0.1938   -0.1469    0.0563    0.0031   -0.0156
```

and this is a segment of nom (Columns 493 through 498)

```
1.0904    1.0235    1.0881    1.0368    1.0769    1.0514
1.0685    1.0201    1.0769    1.0272    1.0497    1.0532
1.0928    1.0180    1.1210    1.0201    1.0568    1.0685
1.0568    1.0285    1.1001    1.0170    1.0952    1.0260
1.0952    1.0078    1.1380    1.0107    1.1026    1.0272
1.0928    1.0078    1.1077    1.0212    1.0463    1.0480
```

Why is this division leading to this result? I've tried dividing with rdivide, in a double for loop, and row by row in a for loop. All number types are double.

Comment: Those zeros in `Rlayer` are almost certainly non-zero. I believe they are just smaller than 10E-4, so Matlab isn't displaying the nonzero digits. Are you sure the entries aren't correct? Try testing something like `nom(1,1) / denom(1,1) == Rlayer(1,1)`.

Comment: Try typing `format long g` in the command line and then type `Rlayer`

Comment: First of all, your question is not clear and be careful: I think you meant NUMERATOR and NOT NOMINATOR.
Plus I did not understand the sense of the operation 
               
        nom=((firstd.^2)+1).^1.5;

Are you sure that the exponent factor was not put outside the resulting matrix?
As Chuck suggested try to perform the result between some elements and compare the results.

Comment: I feel awful, because I fixed this issue about ten minutes after I wrote this. You're right, Rlayer was nonzero. I currently can't edit the post.